# 6 abstractions, 1 construct

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, abstraction, readability, clarity

Which do you prefer, and why:

Typical

```
if (this.sun.hidden === true &&
    this.moon.visible === false) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

Possible unnecessary abstraction

```
if (isSunHidden() === true &&
    isMoonVisible() === false) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

Removing some syntax

```
if (isSunHidden() &&
    isMoonVisible()) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

I like this one as its very readable, but also requires a hard-coded "daytime" string

```
if (timeOfDay() === "daytime") {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

This is also easy to read

```
if (isItDaytime()) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

Mixes printing with time of day checking, not good

```
printDaytime();
```

Anyway, this is personal preference to a large degree, but there also good, logical reasons to prefer one over the other and I am interested in hearing those reasons - or possibly other variations of the same construct if it adds anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Of your options, I prefer:

```
if (isItDaytime()) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

This one is also not terrible:

```
if (timeOfDay() === "daytime") {
    print "its daytime"
}
```

...though I would use an enumeration or similar construct instead of the literal string, like:

```
if (timeOfDay() === TimeOfDay.DAY_TIME) {
    print "its daytime"
}
```